# Moment.js with $ undefined

Tags: momentjs

When package is installed I receive '$ is undefined' from ender.js within the node_modules.

Is moment working with any additional dependencies or what am I missing?

Thanks

edit: Error is received when I run webdriver with cucumber.

Comment: did you try to reference JQuery?

Comment: No as nothing in their documentation suggests a jquery dependency. I might as well be wrong, will try it out now.